# grunt cssmin different target files for style.min.css and above-the-fold.min.css

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-cssmin

In an older version of cssmin it was possible to create to different target files. I minified a style.min.css and an above-the-fold.min.css. Now I updated to a newer version of nodejs, npm, grunt and cssmin and it is not possible to minify to different outputfiles anymore. Since the update grunt only minifies the second task and skip the first task. Do you have a hint for me to minify both tasks?

```
cssmin: {
  options: {
    mergeIntoShorthands: false,
    roundingPrecision: -1
  },
  target: {
    files: {
      'data/style.min.css': ['a.css', 'b.css', 'c.css', 'd.css', 'e.css', 'f.css', 'g.css']
    }
  }
},


penthouse: {
 extract : {
    outfile : 'data/above-the-fold.temp.css',
    css : './data/style.min.css',
    url : 'http://localhost/',
    width : 1280,
    height : 500
 },
},

cssmin: {
  options: {
    mergeIntoShorthands: false,
    roundingPrecision: -1
  },
  target: {
    files: {
      'data/above-the-fold.min.css': ['data/above-the-fold.temp.css']
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[grunt-contrib-cssmin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin) will allow multiple Targets to be defined in a single Task. For example:

**Gruntfile.js**

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  grunt.initConfig({ 
    // ...
    cssmin: { // <-- cssmin Task
      options: {
        mergeIntoShorthands: false,
        roundingPrecision: -1
      },
      targetA: { // <-- First target
         files: {
          'data/style.min.css': ['a.css', 'b.css', 'c.css', 'd.css', 'e.css', 'f.css', 'g.css']
        }
      },
      targetB: { // <-- Second target
        files: {
          'data/above-the-fold.min.css': ['data/above-the-fold.temp.css']
        }
      }
    }
    // ...
  });

  // ...
};
```

Each Target name should be unique within the `cssmin` Task. For example: `targetA` and `targetB`

As you've included the `penthouse` Task in your post, I guess that you need to run that *after* generating the `style.min.css` file, and *before* generating the `above-the-fold.min.css`. To do this you can register your Tasks as follows:

```js
grunt.registerTask('default', ['cssmin:targetA', 'penthouse', 'cssmin:targetB',]);
```

**Note**: The use of the semi-colon notation, namely `cssmin:targetA` and `cssmin:targetB`. This simply ensures that `targetA` of the `cssmin` Task is run before the `penthouse` Task. Subsequently, (when the `penthouse` Task completes), `targetB` of the `cssmin` Task is run.